# NGINX Redirect to HTTPS Minus a Subdirectory?

Tags: nginx

Nginx is new to me. I'm currently redirecting http to https using the following.

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

How would I do the same except not redirect anything going to subfolder /abcd/ ?
I've tried using location blocks, but it gives me a "too many redirects" error when loading the site.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement suggests that you are processing `http` and `https` requests in the same `server` block. You need to use two `server` blocks. This will remove the `if` block and allow you to use simple `location` blocks to handle the excluded directories.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /abcd/ {
        ...
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
}
```